Open a url with a custom protocol from the command line
xdg-open can open urls, but only ones starting with ftp, http or https. But my browser will happily open other urls in programs that have a handler for it registered, e.g. f5-vpn:// urls (for a vpn, this launches the vpn client after authenticating in a web app).
How can I open other urls like f5-vpn:// with their registered handler from the command line, just like the browser does?

xdg-open can handle any URI scheme, as long as it’s registered with a handler for the corresponding x-scheme-handler MIME type. To do this, add an entry to ~/.config/mimeapps.list ($XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mimeapps.list), in the “Default Applications” section, pointing to the appropriate .desktop file. For example:
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/f5-vpn=firefox-esr.desktop


This works (with x-scheme-handler/f5-vpn). xdg-open now starts the vpn client. But the vpn client is registered to receive urls to open through dbus, so it just closes again after a timeout. Can xdg-open do opening through dbus? (When opening the url from the browser, that works.)

Have you configured the scheme to open the VPN client, or the browser?

More explicitly, the idea behind using firefox.desktop (or equivalent for your browser of choice) to handle f5-vpn: is that, since the browser already does the right thing, asking it to handle such URIs from xdg-open (and others) should produce the desired behaviour. Asking the VPN client to handle f5-vpn: is unlikely to be as effective.

The scheme opens the VPN client. The .desktop file is installed by the client installer, and that is how the browser knows to open the client. If I change the handler, the browser is no longer able to open the client. In addition, the client also installs /usr/share/dbus-1/services/com.f5.f5vpn.service, but the .desktop file also contains a DBusActivatable=true key.  Not sure which of those tells the browser to use DBus.

Ah, right, that’s https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/dbus.html but xdg-open doesn’t support that.
